# Why does SimpleDateFormat show unix date as December 31 1969?

Tags: java, android, date

I am working on a date picker where there is a range of dates. I noticed that all of my dates are a day behind and while investigating the issue I narrowed down the problem to the SimpleDateFormat object. No matter what Unix time I give it it sets the date to the previous day. An example of this behaviour is

```
String myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat);

Log.d(TAG, "Time Zone: " + cal.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
Log.d(TAG, "Printable: " + sdf.format(0));
```

The output that I see in the logger is

```
Time Zone: UTC
Printable: 12/31/1969
```

Why does the formatter use December 31 instead of January 1st 1970?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `DateFormat` also has a `TimeZone` (and your system isn't set to UTC). You can change it with [`DateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29). Something like

```
String myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println("Printable: " + sdf.format(0));
```

Output is (as you expected)

```
Printable: 01/01/1970
```

Comment: Interesting. Why does it do this though when the calendars Time zone is set to be UTC?

Comment: @nbroeking What if you have two, or more, `Calendar`(s)?